# Password with regular password

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have to do the password by this condition for creating password to follow this characteristics :

- Contain at least 12 alphanumeric characters.
- Contain both upper and lower case letters.
- Contain at least one number (for example, 0-9).
- Contain at least one special character (for example,!$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,/).

  i did this :

  ```
  <input type="password" required pattern="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*
   [!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*{}()_=+]{12,}$"                                              
   name="password" 
   nblur="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch 
    ? 'Password must contain at least 12 characters, including upper 
   lowercase numbers and least special character' : ''); 
   if(this.checkValidity()) form.password1.pattern = this.value;">
  ```

  but when i try to put a password and confirm it always return not valid password

Sorry for this question, but with regExpression i put for this characteritics. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a series of test in JavaScript and control the `submit` event for your form.

```js
var testPassword = (function() {
  var allTests = [];
  var minimumAlphaNumericCharacters = 12;

  function countAlphanumeric(password) {
    var count = password.length - password.replace(/[a-z]|\d/ig, '').length;
    if (count < minimumAlphaNumericCharacters) {
      return "Too few Alphanumeric Characters! At least " + minimumAlphaNumericCharacters + " nedded, " + count + " found";
    }
    return true;
  }
  allTests.push(countAlphanumeric);

  function containsUpperAndLowerCharacters(password) {
    var test = (password === password.toLowerCase());
    if (test) {
      return "Must contain both upper and lower case characters";
    }
    return true;
  }
  allTests.push(containsUpperAndLowerCharacters);
  var minimumDigits = 1;

  function containsMinimumDigits(password) {
    var test = password.replace(/\D/ig, '').length;
    if (test < minimumDigits) {
      return "Must contain at least " + minimumDigits + " digits, " + test + " digits found";
    }
    return true;
  }
  allTests.push(containsMinimumDigits);
  var minimumSpecials = 1;

  function containsMinimumSpecials(password) {
    var test = password.replace(/\w/ig, '').length;
    if (test < minimumSpecials) {
      return "Must contain at least " + minimumSpecials + " special symbols, " + test + " special symbols found";
    }
    return true;
  }
  allTests.push(containsMinimumSpecials);
  return function testPassword(password) {
    return allTests
      .map(function(test) {
        return test(password);
      })
      .filter(function(test) {
        return test !== true;
      });
  };
})();
//TEST
var form = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("form"));
var input = form.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("pre"));
input.onchange = input.onkeyup = form.onsubmit = function(evt) {
  var password = input.value.toString();
  var test = testPassword(password);
  output.textContent = test.join("\n");
  if (evt.type == "submit") {
    alert((test.length < 1 ? "Good" : "Bad") + " Password");
  }
  return false;
};
```